# Part-time PhD in Mathematics (UK)

Tags: phd, mathematics

I am interested in pursuing post-graduate (PhD) studies in Mathematics, preferably applied/financial mathematics with scientific computing combined. I have undergrad and grad degree in quantitative fields (maths/stats), and I am much more interested in reading/writing papers/research than just go through another taught degree where quite often one has to regurgitate things but not really do what one wants.

I am, however, not able to do so as a full-time student - full time work / life, so I am only planning on doing this part-time. However, this would help with work as I already work in the field, so would ideally be able to curb things so that I take advantage of the studies and apply them to work.

There are universities (BTW: I'm in London, UK) which offer part-time PhD, provided you can really commit and have an impeccable time management.

**Question is**: has anyone (successfully) done this and what would be your recommendation?

PS. Not looking for answers like 'it's too difficult/intensive' or 'part-time PhD has no value'. I want to do this because *I* care and because *I* am interested in this; it's not about (greatly) improving career prospects.

Comment: Aa a small hint, in my experience for such things, it helps if the employer supports it. If you can do something that is somehow - even just remotely - related with your work or where someone at your work could even be advisor, you can plan it into your work life. For a lot of people it is easier (motivation/organisation-wise) to do it, if they can consider it part of their work-life and work on it in their work environment. It also may give you free peers to discuss things with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to work full time and complete a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/is-it-possible-to-work-full-time-and-complete-a-phd)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here. You're considering a part-time PhD and want to know... what? Whether it's possible? Whether it's a good idea? Something else?